# Get result on Ajax from node js server

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax

I'm trying to check if a token input sent from front (ajax) to back (node js) is correct,

if the token is found on the User collection, status(200) is returned, else status (400) is returned

```
const checktoken = async (req, res) => {
    const token = req.body.token

    User.findOne({ 
     'token': token }, (err, user) => {

       if (user) {
         return res.status(200)

       } else {
        return res.status(404)
       }
    })
  }
```

and on ajax side

my problem is that the alert on the client-side is always GOOD TOKEN whenever the token is good or not

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/token',
  type: "POST",
  statusCode: {
    200: function(response) {
      alert('GOOD TOKEN');
    },
    404: function(response) {
      alert('WRONG TOKEN');
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: I don't know much about how to code in `node.js` but what is `user`? you are not sending any data in the ajax request thus there won't be any `response` in the function so you can delete that.

Comment: It looks like an ORM, a tool to link some code to a database. I think here, a table or collection or whatever is called ```User```

Comment: User is a collection on mongodb that contains token entry